# Concatening values in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to produce a unique value for a date so I can bucket table rows based on their date values. I tried doing this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(TO_VARCHAR(YEAR($1)), TO_VARCHAR(DAYOFYEAR($1))) 
FROM VALUES ('2022-01-01'), ('1972-10-01')
```

I would expect this to produce the following results:

|  | Column1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20221 |
| 2 | 19721 |

However, I'm actually receiving an error:

> Function EXTRACT does not support VARCHAR(10) argument type

I have no idea what the term, `EXTRACT`, is, and this appears like it should work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a slight adjustment. As long as the date strings are YYYY-MM-DD there's no conversion required from the date strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT(year($1::date), DAYOFYEAR($1::date)) 
FROM VALUES ('2022-01-01'), ('1972-10-01')
```

However, the output is different. Since you're using DAYOFYEAR, the second row will have 275 for the day of year.

| CONCAT(YEAR($1::DATE), DAYOFYEAR($1::DATE)) |
| --- |
| 20221 |
| 1972275 |